# How to get the notification when the iphone screen orientation changed

Tags: macos, avfoundation, record

I am write an OSX (Mac) app to record iPhone screen using AVfoundation like QTPlayer.

But,when my phone screen orientation changed,I dont konw how to get a notification. I try to seek solutions from delegates ,notifications,but got nothing.And,I cant get the iphone screen size.

I used the AVCaptureInput AVCaptureSession  AVCaptureDevice and so on.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved.
You need to add a notification called **AVCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification**,like this :

```
NSNotificationCenter *notiCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
id inputPortFormatDescriptionOberserver = [notiCenter addObserverForName:AVCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
        didGetVideoDimensions = YES;
        [wself.screenRecorderDelegate captureInputPortDidChanged];
        NSLog(@"AVCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification");
    }];
```

**And you can get the screen size like this :**

```
- (CGSize)optedDeviceSize{
CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
AVCaptureInputPort *port = self.videoDeviceInput.ports.firstObject;
if (port) {
    CMVideoDimensions videoDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(port.formatDescription);
    size = CGSizeMake(videoDimensions.width, videoDimensions.height);
}
return size;
```

}